# How to manage changed items and their previous names in database

Tags: sql-server, database-design

How does one handle situation when you have sales orders and items tables, and then at one point in time you have to change an item. The change will also show up on sales order that have that item. However, lets say that at the time the sales order was place the information was correct but changed later. I don't want older SOs to change what they show for line items and I don't want to have to make new items because it will confuse me later which item is correct.

I noticed that in OpenERP it does just that, keeps the name of part number and description on sales order even if you changed it after sales order was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating new database restructure your Item table. Create a table (for e.g. `ItemHistory`). have a `ItemID` and `ItemTypeID` and `DateCreated` Fields on it.

ItemID should be used for orders and `ItemTypeID` + `DateCreated` will help you to get the current Item.

Comment: Does this mean I would have to make two items table and copy one item to the other when order is created?

Comment: @DennisZaitsev No you don't need to create two Item tables. `ItemTable` will have `ItemDetails`, `ItemStatus` (Active or Not), ItemType (Foreign key from `ItemTypeTable`). In `ItemTypeTable` you will store the ItemType (e.g. Iphone4, Iphone4s, Nokia Luma etc). Each time you update a Item details. Create a new record in 'ItemTable' with its status as active and Update the old Record status as inactive. Join with `ItemTypeTable` will help you to get the result quickly. It will allow you to access the old details as well as the recent details of item.